# mongodb: sort nested array using dynamic parmeter of field name

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregate

Assume in an aggregation pipeline one of the steps produces the following results:

```
{
    customer: "WN",
    sort_category: "category_a",
    locations: [ 
        {
            city: "Elkana", 
            category_a: 11904.0, 
            category_b: 74.0,
            category_c: 657.0,
        }, 
        {
            city: "Haifa",
            category_a: 20.0,
            category_b: 841.0,
            category_c: 0,
        }, 
        {
            city" : "Jerusalem",
            category_a: 451.0,
            category_b: 45.0,
            category_c: 712.0,
        }
    ]
}
{
...
}
```

The next step is to sort the list of the nested objects of each document in the collection.

The list of the nested objects should be sorted by dynamic parameter containing the field name.

For example - the list of `locations` should be sorted by the value of `category_a`.

`category_a` is parmeter given in `sort_category` field.

Comment: The main challenge in the above case is that each document in the collection can be sorted by a different field, depending on the parameter that appears at the top of the document.

Comment: I think it is not possible with $sort operator or any other operator, might be need to create own operator using $function in v4.4, which platform are you using to execute this query? ex. nodejs? what is the mongodb version are you using?

Comment: mongodb version 4.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution without use `$function`:

```
db.tests.aggregate([
    {$unwind:"$locations"}, 
    {$project: {
        _id: 1,
        customer: 1,
        sort_category: 1,
        locations: 1,
        locationsKV:{$objectToArray:"$locations"}
        }
    }, 
    {$unwind:"$locationsKV"}, 
    {$project:{
        _id: 1,
        customer: 1,
        sort_category: 1,
        locations: 1,
        locationsKV: 1,
        category: {
            $cond:[{$eq: ["$sort_category","$locationsKV.k"]}, 
            "$locationsKV.v", 0]},
        agg: {
            $cond: [{$eq: ["$sort_category","$locationsKV.k"]}, true, false]
            }
        }
    }, 
    {$match: {agg: true}}, 
    {$sort: {category: 1}}, 
    {$group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        customer: {$first: "$customer"},
        sort_category: {$first: "$sort_category"},       
        locations: {$push: "$locations"}
        }
    }, 
    {$project:{ _id: 0}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try custom way,

- `$addFields` will add one copy field named `category` of key `sort_category` inside every object in `locations` array using `$map` and `$reduce`
- `$unwind` deconstruct `locations` array
- `$sort` by `category` field that we have added in `locations` array
- `$project` to remove `category` field
- `$group` by _id and reconstruct `locations` array
- `$project` to remove `_id` field

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      locations: {
        $map: {
          input: "$locations",
          as: "l",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$l",
              {
                category: {
                  $reduce: {
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$$l" },
                    initialValue: null,
                    in: {
                      $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$this.k", "$sort_category"] }, "$$this.v", "$$value"]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$locations" },
  { $sort: { "locations.category": 1 } },
  { $project: { "locations.category": 0 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      customer: { $first: "$customer" },
      sort_category: { $first: "$sort_category" },
      locations: { $push: "$locations" }
    }
  },
  { $project: { _id: 0 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PikgCqwI4s6)

---

If you are planing to upgrade your **MongoDB to v4.4** or also this will helpful for others, The [$function](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/index.html) is a option for custom operation and user defined operation.

There are 3 properties:

- `body` The function definition. You can specify the function definition as either BSON type Code or String, define our own function using `function(){`, we have passed `locations` array and `sort_category` that is dynamic field, the function logic is sort by descending order
- `args` Arguments passed to the function body
- `lang` The language used in the body. You must specify lang: "js"

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      locations: {
        $function: {

          body: function(locations, sort_category){
            return locations.sort(function(a, b){
              // DESCENDING ORDER
              return b[sort_category] - a[sort_category]
              // ASCENDING ORDER
              // return a[sort_category] - b[sort_category]
            })
          },

          args: ["$locations", "$sort_category"],

          lang: "js"

        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

For more guidelines about restrictions and considerations [Refer](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/index.html#considerations).

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using `$function`?

Comment: i never seen any example with other operators, I am not sure, also searching for you, will update you if it is possible.

Comment: I found a solution without using `$function` (see the answer below).

Comment: @ElhananSchwarts i have added one another way you can prevent second copy of locations array and second unwind pipeline. means this is little optimized version of your query.